# numpy vectorization of double python for loop

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

V is (n,p) numpy array typically dimensions are n~10, p~20000

The code I have now looks like

```
A = np.zeros(p)
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i+1):
        A += F[i,j] * V[i,:] * V[j,:]
```

How would I go about rewriting this to avoid the double python for loop?

Comment: What is the shape of `F`? Is it `(n, n)` or `(n, n, p)`?

Comment: did you consider writing those for-loops in C (since they are simple), and using scipy.weave.blitz ?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid cython or weave.blitz for the moment if some python code will be "good enough"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Isaac's answer seems promising, as it removes those two nested for loops, you are having to create an intermediate array `M` which is `n` times the size of your original `V` array. Python for loops are not cheap, but memory access ain't free either:

```
n = 10
p = 20000
V = np.random.rand(n, p)
F = np.random.rand(n, n)

def op_code(V, F):
    n, p = V.shape
    A = np.zeros(p)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i+1):
            A += F[i,j] * V[i,:] * V[j,:]
    return A

def isaac_code(V, F):
    n, p = V.shape
    F = F.copy()
    F[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = 0
    M = (V.reshape(n, 1, p) * V.reshape(1, n, p)) * F.reshape(n, n, 1)
    return M.sum((0, 1))
```

If you now take both for a test ride:

```
In [20]: np.allclose(isaac_code(V, F), op_code(V, F))
Out[20]: True

In [21]: %timeit op_code(V, F)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit isaac_code(V, F)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.3 ms per loop
```

So removing the for loops is costing you an 8x **slowdown**. Not a very good thing... At this point you may even want to consider whether a function taking about 3ms to evaluate requires any further optimization. IN case you do, there's a small improvement which can be had by using `np.einsum`:

```
def einsum_code(V, F):
    n, p = V.shape
    F = F.copy()
    F[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = 0
    return np.einsum('ij,ik,jk->k', F, V, V)
```

And now:

```
In [23]: np.allclose(einsum_code(V, F), op_code(V, F))
Out[23]: True

In [24]: %timeit einsum_code(V, F)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop
```

So that's roughly a 20% speed up that introduces code that may very well not be as readable as your for loops. I would say not worth it...

Comment: Did not know about `einsum`; very neat!

Comment: Yep.  One common heuristic for vectorizing code when it's a little troublesome to do the whole thing is to vectorize over the long axes and loop over the short ones, which gets you almost all the benefit for a fraction of the headache.  But here, that's what the OP had already done!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with the einsum method after testing each with a range of inputs (n=5-30 & p=100-20000), I was not aware it was there.

Answer (score 7):

The difficult part about this is that you only want to take the sum of the elements with `j <= i`. If not for that then you could do the following:

```
M = (V.reshape(n, 1, p) * V.reshape(1, n, p)) * F.reshape(n, n, 1)
A = M.sum(0).sum(0)
```

If `F` is symmetric (if `F[i,j] == F[j,i]`) then you can exploit the symmetry of `M` above as follows:

```
D = M[range(n), range(n)].sum(0)
A = (M.sum(0).sum(0) - D) / 2.0 + D
```

That said, this is really not a great candidate for vectorization, as you have `n << p` and so your `for`-loops are not going to have much effect on the speed of this computation.

**Edit**: As Bill said below, you can just make sure that the elements of `F` that you don't want to use are set to zero first, and then the `M.sum(0).sum(0)` result will be what you want.

Comment: What about `F[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = 0`? That way the upper half of `F` (offset by 1) is zero and will not contribute to the sum.

Comment: Also, `a.sum(0).sum(0)` can be written as `np.sum(a, (0,1))` or `a.sum((0,1))` which isn't any faster but I find it more readable.

Comment: As I said, this code is really not a good candidate for vectorization.

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be written as

[image: formula]

and thus you can sum it like this using the `np.newaxis`-construct:

```
na = np.newaxis
X = (np.tri(n)*F)[:,:,na]*V[:,na,:]*V[na,:,:]
X.sum(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
```

Here a 3D-array `X[i,j,p]` is constructed, and then the 2 first axes are summed, which results in a 1D array `A[p]`. Additionaly `F` was multiplied with a triangular matrix to restrict the summation according to the problem.